# What causing the axis of rotation of a bowling ball to change

Tags: rigid-body-dynamics

A bowler throw a bowling ball with an initial velocity and initial rotation. Let the initial velocity vector be parallel to the y-axis. Now, the ball is rotating about an axis, call that the axis of rotation. This axis will form 2 angles from the velocity vector. Call the angle above the plane of the lane the "axis tilt". Call the angle in the plane of motion the "axis rotation".

[image: Angle between axis of rotation and ball velocity]

The ball is initially rolling with sliding. The with sliding will result in a force that causes the ball to hook (change direction until the rotation vector line up with the velocity vector).

What is the cause of the axis of rotation changing, such that, 1) the axis tilt will drop to 0 and 2) the axis rotation change toward the velocity vector.

Comment: Analyzing the 'rolling AND sliding' phase is difficult to say the least.  Sounds like you're asking about the conservation of angular momentum when the ball ceases to slide?

Comment: No. Asking about the sliding phase. I understand how the sliding causes the ball to "hook". The slippage produces a force which could be broken down into 2 vectors -- one parallel to the ball velocity, slowing it down, and the other at a right angle, acting on the ball to change direction.

I think this sliding force also torque the ball, which changes the axis of rotation. I just don't know how exactly. From observation, I can see the axis of rotation changing as described above.

Comment: Animation of the change in axis of rotation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_FUt7KzhHM